# Steps to connect a RASA chatbot to Twilo

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

Can i have the steps to connect rasa chatbot to twilio.I already have ngrok and a demo bot.All i need is the commands and url and where to put that in the twilio,in incoming message or callback url as such.please guide me through it ,i cant find a proper documentation for rasa twilio integration for rasa chatbot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to Twilio and create a project "Programmable SMS".
- https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/dashboard and click on "Show API Credentials" (top/right)
- Copy there information and add in your credentials.yml (like in the docs Rasa Twilio)

```
    twilio:
    account_sid: "ACbc2dxxxxxxxxxxxx19d54bdcd6e41186"
    auth_token: "e231c197493a7122d475b4xxxxxxxxxx"
    twilio_number: "+440123456789"
```

- Use the ngrok on the port where rasa is running (normally it's 5005).
- Add your URL (ngrok url + "/webhooks/rest/webhook") for message incomes in https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/sandbox

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about integrating Twilio with Rasa here - https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/twilio/.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, RASA library may not read from credentials.yml file, In that case, it's better to set as environment variables like below or you can keep in env file.

```
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=ACbc2dxxxxxxxxxxxx19d54bdcd6e41186
export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=e231c197493a7122d475b4xxxxxxxxxx
```